# Server Side Includes

Tags: html, apache2, server-side-includes

I got the following error message in the Apache log:

```
unable to include potential exec "header.html" in parsed file /Users/sikusiku/Sites/ss-git/homepage.shtml
```

I basically tried to include *header.html* from *homepage.shtml*. I used the very basic directive in *homepage.html* (both *header.html* and *homepage.shtml* are located in the document root):

```
<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->
```

I think I have properly turned on the SSI in my *httpd.conf*:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
...
AddType text/html .shtml
...
# XBitHack doesn't have anything to do with this, but I added it anyway.
XBitHack on
```

Did I miss anything? Does the included file i.e. *header.html* need to be configured differently?

Comment: You don't need the XBitHack when you've named the file shtml. And if the header.html is in the same directory like the shtml, just do a <!--#include file="header.html" -->

Comment: Try virtual="/header.html". Otherwise; the error seems to imply some permission error. Try to chmod the header.html to not be executable.

Comment: Unfortunately, those two suggestions didn't work.

Comment: One other thing that's different at my site: I have "Options +Includes" in the apache config. Has the error message in the logfile changed?

Comment: Tried `Options +Includes`, `Options Includes -IncludesNOEXEC`... none worked.

Comment: What's the message in the apache error log now? Same or different?

Comment: Sorry, I have another directive in the config: AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .html

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this problem myself on ubuntu sever 11.10 with apache2.

my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I changed AllowOverride None to All in /var/www directory directive.

my .htaccess file in /var/www/.htaccess:

```
Options +Includes
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

finally i made sure that include.load was in the mods-enabled folder this is to load the mod_includes.so module.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/include.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/include.load
```

That creates a symbolic link to the include.load in mods-available.

finally restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That made it work for me, hope you get it working as well.

--
Thomas

Comment: Note: ubuntu / debian apache2 has a different config pattern then the stock apache2. this can make a big difference in how something is configured see: http://www.control-escape.com/web/configuring-apache2-debian.html